# Cannot start service MySQL 5.7 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to start MySQL service but encountering this error:

```
root@orangepiplus2e:~# systemctl start mysql.service

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: OK so what's the output of `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: root@orangepiplus2e:~# systemctl status mysql.service

* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-07-26 08:07:25 +07; 2min 58s ago
  Process: 1710 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
@Kulfy

Comment: Do You have any errors in the logs `/var/log/mysql/error.log` ?